# Error in logging into Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, mount

After doing a regular update, the system hangs on:

[image: Blinking Cursor and Black Screen]

I tried to login using Live CD and it seems that the used partition is not mounted any more.

```
/dev/loop0 squashfs         /rofs          
/dev/sda1                   (not mounted)  
/dev/sda5                   (not mounted)  
/dev/sdb1  vfat    UBUNTU 16_0 /cdrom      96E9-5126
```

How could I fix this problem without losing any of the data?

Comment: could you try switching VTs at the blank screen? ctrl-alt F1 or some other function key would do the trick

Comment: I tried ctrl+alt+f1, shift, f8, ... but it seems that it doesn't respond to any input from keyboard.